# Format data queryset result to use in form.ModelChoiceField queryset option

Tags: python, django, forms, django-queryset, modelchoicefield

I have a project in Django, with data in a Postgres database.

I want to create a form with a ModelChoiceField where I can select the data obtained in a previous queryset.

When I make the queryset to get data from the database:

```
list_result_queryset = BdimMaestraDatos.objects.filter(fecha_baja__isnull=True).values_list('nombre').distinct()
```

I get this result:

```
<QuerySet [('PEDRO',), ('JUAN',), ('ANDRES',), ('PABLO',), ('SOFIA',)]>
```

And when I show the results in the de template, they are offered but with a "dirty" format like parenthesis, coma, etc.

Please, How can I show it in the form?ModelChoiceField query option only the names PEDRO, JUAN, PABLo, etc and not ('PEDRO',), ('JUAN',), etc.?

This is my `form.py` code

```
from django import forms
from .models import BdimMaestraDatos,

lista_queryset_nombres_activos = BdimMaestraDatos.objects.filter(fecha_baja__isnull=True).values_list('nombre').distinct()
print('Resultado Queryset values list: %s' %lista_queryset_nombres_activos)

class MaestraDatosForm(forms.Form):
    Seleccionar_Nombre = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="Nombre", queryset=lista_queryset_nombres_activos)
```

This is my BdimMaestraDatos model

```
class BdimMaestraDatos(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(db_column='NOMBRE', max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    cc = models.CharField(db_column='CC', max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    estado = models.DecimalField(db_column='ESTADO', max_digits=1, decimal_places=0, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    red = models.CharField(db_column='RED', max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    ger = models.CharField(db_column='GER', max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    est = models.TextField(db_column='EST', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. This field type is a guess.
    fecha_baja = models.DateField(db_column='FECHA_BAJA', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    fecha_alta = models.DateField(db_column='FECHA_ALTA', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'BDIM_MAESTRA_DATOS'
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `.values()`...

Comment: Can you share the `BdimMaestraDatos` model?

Comment: @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike, I added de BdimMaestraDatos model, please, can you help me how to get the data in cleaned format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I solved my problem, and now data displayed in the forms.ModelChoiceField are clean.

The solution was add the argument `flat=True` in the value_list after the field that is filtered.

```
list_result_queryset = BdimMaestraDatos.objects.filter(fecha_baja__isnull=True).values_list('nombre',**flat=True).distinct()
```

The result returned is that one:

```
<QuerySet ['PEDRO', 'JUAN', 'ANDRES', 'PABLO', 'SOFIA']>
```

Thanks to everyone!